# Unexpected behaviour in noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview

I am animating the height change of a NSTableView based row. I am using noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged for that row to reduce the height by -

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context: NSAnimationContext) -> Void in
    context.duration = 0.5
    self.table.noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged(NSIndexSet(index: rowIndex!))
    }, completionHandler: nil)
```

This works perfectly when the row has a small size and the row's full frame is visible.

If the row height is tall and the row frame is not completely visible, it  causes an issue: the reload of multiple rows, breaking the smooth height reduce animation and causing a lot of flickering.

What is the correct way of reducing the height of a row that has a big height(with animation)?